# Dispatcher has no subscribers for outgoing sftp channel

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-messaging

I'm using spring-integration-sftp and my goal is to push local file to SFTP (just that for now, without confirmation or anything else). My configuration is as follows:

```
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@Configuration
@Lazy
public class SftpConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "toSftpChannel")
    public MessageChannel sftpMessageChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory(
            @Qualifier("sftpDestination") SftpPropertiesService sftpPropertiesService 
    ) {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        factory.setHost(sftpPropertiesService.getServiceHost());
        factory.setPort(22);
        factory.setUser(sftpPropertiesService.getUsername());
        factory.setPassword(sftpPropertiesService.getPassword());
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SftpRemoteFileTemplate sftpRemoteFileTemplate(DefaultSftpSessionFactory dssf,
            @Value("${sftp.output.directory}") String outputDirectory) {
        SftpRemoteFileTemplate template = new SftpRemoteFileTemplate(dssf);
        template.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(outputDirectory));
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler(SftpRemoteFileTemplate sftpRemoteFileTemplate) {
        SftpOutboundGateway gateway =
            new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpRemoteFileTemplate, Command.PUT.getCommand(), "payload");
        gateway.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.FAIL);
        return gateway;
    }

    @MessagingGateway
    public interface OutputSftpGateway {
        @Gateway(requestChannel = "toSftpChannel")
        void sendToSftp(File file);
    }
}
```

and sending is just

```
private final OutputSftpGateway outputSftpGateway;
...
outputSftpGateway.sendToSftp(file);
```

When I'm running my code I at first get

```
A bean definition with name 'toSftpChannel' exists, but failed to be created; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'toSftpChannel': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

which is kind of expected with lazy init (though still will have to fix it), but at the second and subsequent runs I'm getting stuck with

```
Exception occurred during request processing. org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException. Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.toSftpChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
```

I'll honestly admit that I'm new with Spring messaging magic, so the cause is probably very stupid but can someone give me a hint why this is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Show us , please, where you call that gateway from? How does it work without Lazy though ?

Comment: Sorry for late response, and yes, the issue was with lazy init. Made a workaround to get rid of lazy init, everything is working fine now. Post this as an answer, will approve. And thanks for working idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@Lazy` may have some effect on those beans initialization. Consider to divide your configuration logic to extract only those beans which cannot live with `@Lazy`. And don't apply it for those Spring Integration components.